# How can I take string in Core Data in another controller SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, string, core-data, swiftui

In my contentView I have to show a List with the content saved in the Core Data.
In the AddTimerController, on the other hand, I manage the data and save them with CoreData
in TimerCell, on the other hand, I manage the form and data that my cell must have to be displayed in the ContentView, but I cannot recall the data previously saved.

ContentView

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@FetchRequest(entity: Time.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var time: FetchedResults<Time>

@State var isAddTimerShown = false
@State var isOptionShown = false


var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(time, id: \.id) { time in
                    timerCell(remainingSeconds: 0, isCounting: true)

                }
            }

            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: buttonOption,
                trailing: buttonAdd)

        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Timer"), displayMode: .inline)

    }
}

var buttonOption: some View {
    Button(action: { self.isOptionShown = true }) {
        Image(systemName: "option").imageScale(.large)
    }.sheet(isPresented: $isOptionShown) {
    }
}

var buttonAdd: some View {
    Button(action: { self.isAddTimerShown = true }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").imageScale(.large)
    }.sheet(isPresented: $isAddTimerShown) {
        AddTimerController(dismissFlag: self.$isAddTimerShown)
    }
}
```

AddTimerController

```
struct AddTimerController: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Time.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var time: FetchedResults<Time>


    
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    var isAnEdit = false

    
    @Binding var dismissFlag: Bool
    
    @State var isCounting = false
    @State var remainingSeconds = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $username)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
                        
            Text("\(timeString(from: Int(TimeInterval(remainingSeconds))))")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if isCounting && remainingSeconds > 0 {
                        remainingSeconds -= 1
                    }
                }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("+10 SEC") {
                        remainingSeconds += 10
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+30 SEC") {
                        remainingSeconds += 30
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+100 SEC") {
                        remainingSeconds += 100
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Button("+1 m ") {
                        remainingSeconds += 60
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+2 m") {
                        remainingSeconds += 120
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+3 m") {
                        remainingSeconds += 180
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Button("+4 m ") {
                        remainingSeconds += 240
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+5 m") {
                        remainingSeconds += 300
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+10 m") {
                        remainingSeconds += 600
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Button("+15 m ") {
                        remainingSeconds += 900
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+30 m") {
                        remainingSeconds += 1800
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button("+1 h") {
                        remainingSeconds += 3600
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
                
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { self.save() }) {
                        Text("SAV")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)

                    }.padding()
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    
                    Button("Start") {
                        isCounting = true
                    }.padding()
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    
                    Button("STOP") {
                        isCounting = false
                    }.padding()
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    
                    Button("RESET") {
                        isCounting = false
                        remainingSeconds = 0
                    }.padding()
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func timeString(from totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let hours = totalSeconds / 3600
        let minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60
        let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes, seconds)
    }
    
    func save() {
        let student = Time(context: self.moc)
        student.id = UUID()
        student.name = "\(username)"
        student.time = "\(remainingSeconds)"

        try? self.moc.save()
        self.dismissFlag = false

    }
```

TimerCell

```
struct timerCell: View {
    
    let timerCount = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
        
    @FetchRequest(entity: Time.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var time: FetchedResults<Time>
    
    @State var remainingSeconds = 0
    @State var isCounting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Circle().shadow(radius: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                        .overlay(
                            Circle()
                                .padding(.all, 1.0)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        )
                        .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                    
                    Text("self.moc.name")
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .frame(height: 35)
                        .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Start") {
                        isCounting = true
                    }.padding()
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("timer.time")
                        .onReceive(timerCount) { _ in
                            if isCounting && remainingSeconds > 0 {
                                remainingSeconds -= 1
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 94.0)
    }
    
    private func timeString(from totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let hours = totalSeconds / 3600
        let minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60
        let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a Core Data problem, per se. You have a mix of @State variables & core data entities that are not actually sharing information. Further, the underpinning for SwiftUI is to have a single source of truth for you data. You don't have that. You have multiple sources of truth and you wonder why nothing seems to update. First, you need to decide what your source of truth will be and use only that to supply the data. In your case, since you are using a Core Data store, I would simply use that. Only when you add data that is not in the store, should you use local variables.

Comment: @Yrb ok, so i should bring everything to the contentView? initially I have no data, only when I go to the AddTimerController where I insert the time by pressing the buttons and add the name. those data where do I save them?

Comment: When you are adding data to a managed object context, you need to have a local variable to store them until you are ready to add them to the MOC. But only there. Also, you will have to deal with the optionality of the MOC data. As you say, when you first start, no data exists, so you would be trying to display a nil. See [Hacking with Swift: Introduction to using Core Data with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/introduction-to-using-core-data-with-swiftui).

Comment: @and I have not saved in the correct way? I used the "moc" variable.

do I then have to recall that to have the data in the other controller?

Comment: You haven't saved it correctly. the MOC is not a variable like you think it is. Think of it as your implementation of Core Data's reality. That is why it is called a context. Every operation must be done through the context, but the context is NOT the thing that holds the data. The Entity is. And each bit of data is held in the Attributes. Please review the tutorial at the link it will give you a good foundation to start using Core Data.